# Is there a way for me to automate the file manager on my Raspberry pi 3B running Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on a project that edits photos of mine and then uploads those photos to a google site. I'm using Selenium to upload the photos to the portfolio site, and I have gotten all the way to the part where I cal select the file I want to upload on to the site. The issue I am having is that I need to select the photos from the file manager. I want this part of the process completely automated: does anyone have suggestions on how I can have a python3 script select a file from the file manager?

I have done some research of my own and I came across [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), but I am not entirely sure if this would work for my project purposes.

Here is an example of what I want to automate:[image]

Comment: On Unix you use scripts, setup from the command line, not mouse click emulation on GUIs. You can do it better and much more with scripts.

Comment: @Ingo Thanks for the tip. Do you know what I can google so I can do some reading about these scripts?

Comment: You can look for a [bash scripting tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+scripting+tutorial). But because you want to have it for a python3 script, I suggest to do it all with python3. But it is more a general programming question so I would suggest to ask at https://stackoverflow.com/. I think you will get quicker a better answer.